# Parquet CPP build fails on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, boost, parquet

I'm trying to build the parquet-cpp package following [their instructions](https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp). After `cmake .` and `make` I'm getting the following error.

`cd /go/src/github.com/ascend-io/parquet-cpp/examples && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/reader-writer.dir/link.txt --verbose=1`

```
/usr/bin/g++     -ggdb -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g   CMakeFiles/reader-writer.dir/reader-writer.cc.o  -o ../build/debug/reader-writer -rdynamic ../build/debug/libparquet.a ../arrow_ep/src/arrow_ep-install/lib/libarrow.so ../arrow_ep/src/arrow_ep-install/lib/libarrow_io.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so ../brotli_ep/src/brotli_ep-install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.a ../brotli_ep/src/brotli_ep-install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlienc.a ../brotli_ep/src/brotli_ep-install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.a ../snappy_ep/src/snappy_ep-install/lib/libsnappy.a ../thrift_ep/src/thrift_ep-install/lib/libthriftd.a ../zlib_ep/src/zlib_ep-install/lib/libz.a -Wl,-rpath,/go/src/github.com/ascend-io/parquet-cpp/arrow_ep/src/arrow_ep-install/lib 
../build/debug/libparquet.a(metadata.cc.o): In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:50: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
../build/debug/libparquet.a(metadata.cc.o): In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:365: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/CMakeFiles/reader-writer.dir/build.make:104: recipe for target 'build/debug/reader-writer' failed
make[2]: *** [build/debug/reader-writer] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/go/src/github.com/ascend-io/parquet-cpp'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:652: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/reader-writer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/reader-writer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/go/src/github.com/ascend-io/parquet-cpp'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: It's a link error.  Make sure you have `libboost-all-dev` or the individual `-dev` packages installed.

Comment: already installed all libboost lib, the one from apt-get is 1.58.0

Comment: You misunderstand. That is one (of many) Boost runtime libraries. You are missing the dev package so do 'sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` to ensure you have all of them,

Comment: This may be due to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=823978 You could try to link against a custom (C++11) build of boost and see if that fixes it.

Comment: thanks, this flag works for me.

Comment: @RuiYang what flag?